# How to rotate a tuple?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I have a function with a tuple, example

```
    def rotate_block(block: typing.Tuple[float, float]):
        """
        Rotates a block
        :param block: a block (width_block, height_block)
        """
        return tuple([block[1], block[0]])
```

How do I return the block rotated? I tried this code

```
[(t[1], t[0]) for t in block]
```

But it doesnt work, why?

My output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\algorithms\test_unit.py", line 18, in test_rotate_block
    self.assertEqual(tg.rotate_block((3,1)), (1,3))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\algorithms\xx.py", line 31, in rotate_block
    [tuple(reversed(t)) for t in block]
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\algorithms\xx.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    [tuple(reversed(t)) for t in block]
TypeError: 'int' object is not reversible
```

Comment: Use `r = [(j, i) for (i, j) in tuple_list]`

Comment: i changed my question

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work
Show us what was the output

Comment: @will Downvote: You say: *But it doesnt work, why?*, then please provide a  [mre]. Also read [ask] and review the [tour].

Comment: i added the output

Comment: @will Where in your MRE are you using `reversed`? Please be serious and post a real MRE.

Comment: @will Have you tried what I pointed out in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611125/how-to-rotate-a-tuple#comment126563282_71611125?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special, just use tuple unpacking and then return the block in reversed order:

```
import typing


def rotate_block(block: typing.Tuple[float, float]):
    width, height = block

    return height, width


input_block = (3.14, 2.71)

print(rotate_block(input_block))
```